# ruby on rails sql injection on LIKE '%#{argument}% vulnerable?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, security, sql-injection

I have a question about ruby on rails sql injection vulnerability. let's say i have a method like this:

```
def self.search(args)
 where_clause = `items`.`name` LIKE '%#{args}%'
 results = Item::where(where_clause)
 return results
end
```

where args is a value passed in from the search box. is this vulnerable to attack? My initial thought was that this would be vulnerable to attack, however, after trying a few queries, I wasn't able to.

Is there something special about LIKE '%%' that makes it impervious to attack?

Thanks!

Comment: What database did you try? :)

Comment: just my own local database that we are doing development on.

Comment: What i meant is: mysql, postgre, sqlite, sth else?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: oh, i apologize. it's mysql. I tried a%' or 1=1 'a which allowed me to display all records,  which clearly means it can be injected into, but i wasn't able to get a delete or destroy statement to process

Answer (score 0):

Just to be safe, I ususally do this:

```
Item.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{args}%")
```

Comment: I agree with you, just to be safe I like that approach as well. however, what about LIKE '%%' makes it not vulernable to attack? I've tried a few different angles.